# Put ImageButton on top of ImageView in the same place regardless of resolution

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create an app that requires me to put several ImageButtons on top of an ImageView in certain locations. But since I am relatively new to Android programming and using the different layouts I'm stuck on this problem and could not find a suitable solution so far.

The problem is, as stated in the title, that the ImageButtons change their locations relative to the ImageView on different resolutions. Now that is nothing baffling as the Buttons are placed in relation to the Activity-Borders. I have not found a way yet though, to place them relative to my ImageView.

So any pointers in the right direction here would be a massive help.
Thank you for taking the time to read this and hopefully understanding where my problem lies. I will check back once I wake up tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

use a `RelativeLayout` like this

```
        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bodyLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/base"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE_SOURCE"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/overlay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE_SOURCE"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use layout instead of `ImageView` and `ImageButtons` you can set image to it's background.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/content_bg">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/properties"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/properties"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

not needed use a button every time you can set `OnClickListener` and tech `setOnTouchListener` to any layout like below.

```
    layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

       }
   });

   layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
       }
   });
```